# Trying to configure UberRUSH Javascript Module

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, uber-api

I want to utilize the UserRUSH API that can be found on this link:

[UBERRUSH Javascript API](https://github.com/mjk/uber-rush)

So basically I tried integrating this package by calling

```
npm install uber-rush
```

This created a node_modules folder and the configuration for application.rb is

```rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Workspace
    class Application < Rails::Application
        config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
        config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
    end
end
```

I created a file named donation.js and tried utilizing the UberRUSH module yet I get an error, is there something I have to do to the application.js file to fully configure the node module in Rails?

Answer (score 2):

We have to ways to load node_modules js into rails.

1. Using [bower-rails](https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails)
2. Using [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails)

follow document steps of each gems to load js.

**bower-rails**

- Execute this in terminal after installing of bower-rails. `bower install uber-rush --save` By default assets are put to `/vendor/assets/bower_components folder` in your project
- So add vendor in `asset.rb` `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor')`
- Now add `uber-rush` into `application.js` like this `//= require uber-rush/uber-rush`. Make sure you have `uber-rush.js` file `vendors/assets/bower_components/uber-rush` folder.
- and you are done.

**browserify-rails**

- Please refer this [blog](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/04/bring-commonjs-to-your-asset-pipeline/)

Cheers

Edit: `uber-rush` do not support `bower` package so you have to `bowserify-rails` to load `node_modules` data into your app.